# How to hide only one div when open a page in jQuery and right toggle effect?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I created jQuery slide left and right toggle effect ,the code working good but the problem started when i wanted to hide div (chat) when the page start,
haw i can do this issue ,For see what i did ,you can see here in 
http://jsfiddle.net/KFmLv/5163/

Html:

```
<div id="chat">
  <p><a href="" 

onclick="window.open('','popup','width=600,height=500,scrollbars=yes,resizable=ye

s,toolbar=no,directories=no,location=no,menubar=no,status=no,left=50,top=0'); return 

false">press here to chat.</a></p>
 <div class="toggler">?</div> 
</div>
</div>
```

Css:

```
 #chat {
  position:absolute;

  left:0; width:200px; padding:10px;
 background:red; color:white;
 }
  .toggler {
display: block;
  width:25px; height:50%; color:white; background:blue; text-align:center; 

position:absolute; top:25%; right:-25px; cursor:pointer }
```

Script:

```
$(function(){
  $(".toggler").click(function(e){
    var chat = $("#chat");
    if ($(chat).hasClass("opened")) {
      $(chat).removeClass("opened").animate({"left":0}, 1000);
    } else {
      $(chat).addClass("opened").animate({"left":-$(chat).outerWidth()}, 1000);
    }
  });
});
```

please help me

Comment: Your toggle is inside your chat div.  If you hide it the toggle will also hide.  Are  you wanting to not hide the toggle?

Comment: Yes i want only hide chat div and show toggle when page start

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, pretty much everything is the same, except I defaulted it to start with the open class and it presets the initial 'left'.

http://jsfiddle.net/KFmLv/5165/

```
<div id="chat" class="opened">
    <p><a href="" onclick="window.open('','popup','width=600,height=500,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes,toolbar=no,directories=no,location=no,menubar=no,status=no,left=50,top=0'); return false">press here to chat.</a></p>
    <div class="toggler">?</div>
</div>
```

**SCRIPT:**

```
$(function(){
    var $chat = $("#chat");

    $chat.css('left', -$chat.outerWidth());

    $(".toggler").click(function(e){
        $chat.show();

        if ($chat.hasClass("opened")) {
            $chat.removeClass("opened").animate({"left":0}, 1000);
        } else {
            $chat.addClass("opened").animate({"left": -$chat.outerWidth()}, 1000);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: No this issue i wanted i can do that ,i want the div chat and the div toggler in the one  line as the same as what i did in http://jsfiddle.net/KFmLv/5163

Answer (score 0):

#### Try this:

```js
$(function(){
  $(".toggler").click(function(e){
    var chat = $("#chat");
    if (chat.hasClass("opened")) {
      chat.removeClass("opened").animate({left:0}, 1000);
    } else {
      chat.addClass("opened").animate({left:-$(chat).outerWidth()}, 1000);
    }
  });
});
```

```css
 #chat {
  position:absolute;
   
  left:0; width:200px; padding:10px;
 background:red; color:white;
 }
  .toggler {
display: block;
  width:25px; height:50%; color:white; background:blue; text-align:center; 

position:absolute; top:25%; right:-25px; cursor:pointer }
```

```html
<div id="chat">
  <p><a href="" 

onclick="window.open('','popup','width=600,height=500,scrollbars=yes,resizable=ye

s,toolbar=no,directories=no,location=no,menubar=no,status=no,left=50,top=0'); return 

false">press here to chat.</a></p>
 <div class="toggler">?</div> 
</div>
</div>
```

- Best practice is to declare a `var` referring your element if you are going to use them more than once.
- [**Working CodePen**](http://codepen.io/liorgrs/pen/xZqEyQ)

Enjoy.